# How can I have my SPARQL query results in Turtle format in Apache Jena with commandline interface?

Tags: sparql, apache-jena, turtle-rdf

I have a command

```
./bin/arq  --data ./bin/dbpedia_2015-10.nt  --query ./bin/166.rq
```

which works perfect and I can see my result in my command line interface. I would like to use jena RIOT to have my result in the file.ttl . But as I am not familiar with commandline and linux I don't know how to do it. is there any suggestion. 
I dont want to use the dbpedia datasets niether I just need the results from my sparql query.

this is my code  `

```
select DISTINCT ?instance ?domain ?range ?subClassOf  # 
where { 
   ?instance rdf:type ?type;
             rdfs:domain ?domain;
             rdfs:range ?range;
             rdfs:subClassOf* ?subClassOf.
}
```

`
' but I have the error when change it to construct '

```
construct { DISTINCT ?instance ?domain ?range ?subClassOf.}  
where { 
   ?instance rdf:type ?type;
             rdfs:domain ?domain;
             rdfs:range ?range;
             rdfs:subClassOf* ?subClassOf.
}
```

Comment: If you want your results in any RDF format you'll first have to use a CONSTRUCT query.

Answer (score 1):

It will be in Turtle syntax once you use a `CONSTRUCT` or `DESCRIBE` query.

Comment: this is my code  ` select DISTINCT ?instance ?domain ?range ?subClassOf  # 
where { 
   ?instance rdf:type ?type;
             rdfs:domain ?domain;
             rdfs:range ?range;
             rdfs:subClassOf* ?subClassOf.
} `
' but I have the error when change it to construct 'construct { DISTINCT ?instance ?domain ?range ?subClassOf.}  
where { 
   ?instance rdf:type ?type;
             rdfs:domain ?domain;
             rdfs:range ?range;
             rdfs:subClassOf* ?subClassOf.
}

Answer (score 1):

As you say your aim is to produce Turtle output and Turtle is an RDF serialisation format you need to CONSTRUCT RDF triples. e.g.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
CONSTRUCT { ?instance rdf:type ?type;
            rdfs:domain ?domain ;
            rdfs:range ?range;
            rdfs:subClassOf ?subClassOf .
}
where { 
   ?instance rdf:type ?type;
             rdfs:domain ?domain;
             rdfs:range ?range;
             rdfs:subClassOf* ?subClassOf.
}
```

Comment: Although the answer is syntactically correct, semantically it doesn't make sense form my point of view. I mean, what is the goal of the query? Properties because of the domain and range statements? But what about the `subClassOf` triple pattern then? Is OWL 2 punning used, i.e. the property is also used as a class? Or should it more be `rdfs:subPropertyOf`?